# Does the XBox360 enforce a maximum ping time when connecting to Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360, networking

I have had continuing and intermittent problems connecting to XBOX live using my wireless network.

It connects fine to the network on the diagnostics screen, but frequently has trouble making the last hop to XBox Live over the Internet.

Usually when it does this it complains that it is not getting a response on ICMP (ping) requests. However, if I cross my fingers and make a wish, it connects just fine.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that I use satellite Internet which has horrible ping times. The best ping time I've ever seen on it is around 600ms, and it is usually much worse.

I'm just wondering if MS has some kind of validation when you connect that doesn't let you connect if your ping comes back slower than x, NO XBOX LIVE FOR YOU! Does anyone know if there is a built in check like this and if so, what the magic number is?

**IMPORTANT: Before you say it, I am completely aware that co-op gaming with such lousy ping times is going to be a fruitless effort. The only reason I am trying to get this to work is to facilitate connecting for things like downloading content and patches.**

Comment: "However, if I cross my fingers and make a wish, it connects just fine." Uhh, cross your fingers and make a wish. It seems like it's working for you. :)

Comment: I can't work the controller with my fingers crossed and my genie really needs to get back to his lamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no maximum ping time for LIVE connections.

Once connected, XBox LIVE has a heartbeat timeout of approx. 2 mins