# XBOX 360 - Networking test fails connecting to XBOX Live with ICMP Failure

Tags: networking, technical-issues, xbox-360

I've been around and around, tried a number of things and I just can't seem to make any progress on this. Has anyone got any troubleshooting advice for getting past the dreaded ICMP error during the connectivity test on an XBOX 360?

The test works all the way up to through the Internet connection, but the last test (Connect to XBOX Live) always fails with an ICMP error.

Also, I also get intermittent errors connecting to the marketplace and/or signing in.

I am connecting to the internet wirelessly through a 54G router.

Connecting the XBOX directly to the modem is a major hassle that will involve dragging big honking tv and the xbox to the other end of the house, so I'd prefer not to do that except as an absolute last resort.

Any troubleshooting ideas would be appreciated, for example is there an address I could ping from another computer on the network to see what is going on?

Comment: Slightly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3296/does-the-xbox360-enforce-a-maximum-ping-time-when-connecting-to-xbox-live

Comment: @monorailkitty - yup that is related, but not exactly the same (note that I asked that question too)

Comment: Apologies! I failed to notice that was your question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it could possibly be your router config. Did it work previously then stop either randomly or after an update? There's some surprisingly sane information about ICMP [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080302112403AAqM48r) (ignore the "Best Answer" and look at the other longer one).

If you know your way around a router then you could stick the xbox in the DMZ. If that solved your problem you could be pretty sure your router config is the issue and could then refine it from there.

It would be worth trying a wired connection also, if you could borrow 20m of cat 5 off someone.

Comment: It is already in a DMZ, no dice. That is a good article you referenced though. I'm gonna try a few tips from there and see if I can borrow a long cable from work.

Comment: Checking if your router supports UDP correctly as suggested in the long answer is must.  I used to use DD-WRT firmware on my WRT54G.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried turning everything off then on again...?

Next best option may be to factory reset the router (hold the reset button down for many seconds).

Comment: I've tried both of those options multiple times. I'm actually looking for tips on troubleshooting, rather than taking a shotgun approach.